# How do I connect to an SQL Server d atabase using R and Rstudio? (Mac)

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, rstudio

*Disclaimer: I'm a statistician/bioinformatician by training, so I'm quite new to networks, servers, and databases.*

System: Macbook Pro (M1 chip).

I'm trying to connect to an SQL Server database remotely via R and RStudio.

To start, I ran the following commands in terminal (as seen here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
brew update
HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_FILTERING=1 ACCEPT_EULA=Y brew install msodbcsql18 mssql-tools18
```

The code I'm running in RStudio is as follows (as seen here https://db.rstudio.com/getting-started/connect-to-database):

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver   = "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server",
                      Server   = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx",
                      Database = "Dbname",
                      UID      = "username",
                      PWD      = "password",
                      Port     = 3306,
                      .connection_string ="TrustServerCertificate=yes")
```

The above gives me the following error:

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data
> source name not found and no default driver specified

I can't find any help related to the errors I'm getting at https://db.rstudio.com/getting-started.

Slightly different piece of code gives me a different error:

> con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
> .connection_string = "Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL
> Server};Uid=username;Pwd=password;Host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx;Port=3306;Database=Dbname;TrustServerCertificate=yes;")
>
> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for
> SQL Server]Neither DSN nor SERVER keyword supplied  [Microsoft][ODBC
> Driver 18 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute

---

What is a Server Keyword as referred to in the second error? Is the server supposed to be an IP address as I've indicated in the code?

Does the use of ODBC Driver matter? How can I tell if I'm using the right one?

Am I off the mark with any of the information I'm feeding into dbConnect()?

Any tips welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Why port 3306? Are you trying to connect to a MySQL/MariaDB server? The normal port for the default `MSSQLSERVER` instance is 1433.

Comment: `Invalid connection string attribute`... is probably related to the `Host` keyword. Did you mean to use `Server` instead?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks for the comments. The 3306 port was supplied to me by my server administrator. As for the error mentioned in your second comment, that was my mistake. And now I'm connected! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AlwaysLearning for pointing at the mistake in my second chunk of code. `Host=` should have been `Server=`.

As for the first chunk, I don't know why it wouldn't work.